# Efficiently validate joins (especially row counts) in SQL (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, validation, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I'm working with multiple CTE joins in Snowflake. How are you validating joins? I'm currently validating with a very manual process, checking 1:1 joins, one at a time. I then look for duplicate values, data quality issues, etc. I query the results a few different ways, interrogating specific ways that the join could be improved, noting all the query result counts and resolving differences. The data I'm currently working with should ideally join with the same row count as the base table. One join returns a slightly smaller result and one returns a slightly larger result. There is surely a more efficient way to chase down the root cause than the manual interrogation I'm currently doing.

What I would like to do:
Find a way to return multiple concurrent analyses for me, for example:

- The size of each table prior to joining
- How many rows from each table were included in the join
- How many rows from each table were excluded from the join
- How many rows were used more than once in the "many" portion of a one-to-many join (which I'm currently finding via group by and count(*)>1)

I'm working in Snowflake but I have access to other tools. All ideas welcome.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is:

- How are you validating joins?

- Is there an efficient way to return multiple concurrent analyses such as the examples in the list

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re asking how can you efficiently evaluate a SQL statement to ensure it is returning the correct results. If this is what you are asking then, in my opinion, there is no way of automating this, as every SQL statement is different and I can’t imagine how setting up some sort of framework/automation would be more efficient than just manually running the appropriate checks for a specific statement.

Having a process that you logically work through when checking the results obviously makes sense. However, I can’t see the point of at least some of the checks that you’ve listed - as I don’t see how the information they would provide tell you much about whether your SQL is correct